# Como añadir comillas simples a los valores separados por comas generados por un string.Join

Tags: c#, string, sql

Buneas tardes, tengo una lista de strings que contiene los codigos a añadir a una consulta SQL en un in:
Ejemplo:

```
 List<string> container = new List<string>();
    container.Add("2");
    container.Add("3");
    container.Add("5");
    container.Add("12");
    container.Add("214");
    container.Add("A324");
    container.Add("SD3434");

    string cIn = string.Join(",", container);
  
    string lcSql = "SELECT articulo from ofertas WHERE articulo in(" +cIn + ")";
```

Esto me genera: `SELECT articulo from ofertas WHERE articulo in(2,3,5,12,214,A324,SD3434)`
pero articulo es un campo de tipo `char(10)`, por lo que necesitaría entrecomillar todos los valores del resultado del `string.Join` pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.
¿Puedo hacer esto mediante este método, o busco otra forma?
Gracias.

Comment: [`\'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12107473/10053314)

Comment: @NicolasOñate por favor, elabora una respuesta. Es preferible eso a mandar a alguien a la versión inglesa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones. Una muy sencilla es usar [`Select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) para concatenar las comillas:

```
string cIn = string.Join(",", container.Select(x=> "'" + x + "'"));
```

Esto te devuelve lo siguiente con tu ejemplo:

> SELECT articulo from ofertas WHERE articulo in('2','3','5','12','214','A324','SD3434')

---

Otra opción mas elegante usando `String.Format`:

```
string cIn = string.Join(",", container.Select(x=> string.Format("'{0}'", x)));
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muy agradecido.